# google app engine - set 404 page for php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

I have create a dynamic page for error code 404. How can I set the same in app.yml?

I tried setting error handlers in app.yml but its not working.

```
error_handlers:
- error_code: 404
  file: page404.php
```

It keeps on giving:

```
The url <wrong url> does not match any handlers.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note.

You don't have to use error handlers to deal with 404.  and there is no specific 404 error handler. There is only the following error_handler types

a default handlers and

**over_quota**, which indicates the app has exceeded a resource quota;
**dos_api_denial**, which is served to any client blocked by your app's DoS Protection configuration;
**timeout**, served if a deadline is reached before there is a response from your app.

See docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses

In addition a custom error handler will not render a php script they need to be static html, so if you want your 404 response page to run php then you need to use a normal handler that catches anything not matching one of your handlers, as per the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution:

Add below setting at the end of app.yml. After checking all the formats, it will match the below pattern and throw 404 error page.

```
- url: /.*
  script: page404.php
```

Comment: This may look simple at first (and probably the only way until Google decides to provide actual custom error handler functionality **for HTTP error codes**), but there are caveats to this approach. *First off,* this doesn't actually catch 404 errors. It's simply a fallback handler for any URL that doesn't match handlers **before** it. *Secondly,* you must remember to use [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) in your `page404.php` page to set the HTTP response code correctly (while serving the page) - if that's important (see point 4).

Comment: *Third,* only one handler is used for each request so if you have handlers with wildcard, you will need to have the target PHP files redirect to the 404 page *through code* when the wildcard-based URL doesn't produce a valid response. *Fourth,* some browsers tend to ignore the served page (with response codes other than 200) if they don't hit some criteria. Certain versions of IE are notorious for this, ignoring what it *guesses* to be meaningless dump from the server, and showing a "friendly" error message instead. I guess you can work around it by ignoring point 2 and serving it as HTTP 200.